# Get All Play store search results with PHP scraper (not just top 20)

Tags: php, jquery, scroll, web-crawler, scrape

**Summary :**

I want to fetch all Play store search result, problems is that, Apps that show after scroll that are not show in PHP file_get_content().

**Detail:**

I'm trying to make a php based play store scraper.

I checked all stackoverflow answers and github example, but they all are old, and not working. This is because previously Play store use "start" parameter for more apps/Next page.. Now play store shows more apps on scroll

So after so many research, I decide to make my own scraper.

**What I am doing:**

file_get_contents() : to fetch the query url from play store like so:

```
$result = file_get_content( "https://play.google.com/store/search?q=football" );
```

This only returns 20 apps in the result, I want 250.

Play store shows only 20 apps on the query result, more apps are shown ONLY on scrolling.

I try to get google ajax URL from "network tab", But google use token parameter for next scroll page...

**Questions:**

How can I get scrolled content with PHP? If not possible, how can I get play store all search result?

Otherwise how can I fetch page content with PHP that shows with javascript?

Comment: Have you looked at the AJAX requests behind the google play store? Is there an API?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the store site in chrome dev tools. It has a perfect data source, but you may have trouble getting the tokens. I doubt they want this scraped.

**General**:

> **Request URL:** https://play.google.com/store/apps?authuser=0 
>    **Request Method:** POST 
>    **Status Code:** 200 
>    **Remote Address:** 216.58.220.142:443

**Form Data:**

> **start:** 20 
>   **num:** 5 
>   **numChildren:** 10 
>   **pagTok:** CBQQFA==:S:ANO1ljJ62NU 
>   **ipf:** 1 
>   **xhr:** 1 
>   **token:** OmILlMEkRv_FCJ1tveWI8rtELHQ:1459318564260

Comment: start:20 ??, in my chrome and mozila its show "start:0, num:0.".. i found that, these parameter are not working, play store using token for next page.